# std::unordered_set::find() function faster than std::find()?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I am working on the "first missing positive" solution from LeetCode

https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/submissions/

The first solution was (at 471ms for 171 test cases):

```
#include <unordered_set>
class Solution {
public:
        
    int firstMissingPositive(vector<int>& nums) {
        std::unordered_set<int> s;
        for (auto& n: nums)
            if (n > 0)
                s.insert(n);
        int ret = 1;
        while (s.find(ret) != s.end())
            ret++;
        
        return ret;
    }
};
```

I also tested a simpler solution where numbers are not added to the set, instead I just search the std::vector. This solution exceeded the time limit

```
class Solution {
public:
   
    int firstMissingPositive(vector<int>& nums) {

        int ret = 1; 
        while(std::find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), ret) != nums.end())
            ret ++;
                       
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Strangely, when I took out the condition of `if (n > 0)` in the first solution, to where it was sorting through the entire set every time, it did not exceed the time limit, instead, the resulting runtime actually improved to 394ms

```
#include <unordered_set>
class Solution {
public:
        
    int firstMissingPositive(vector<int>& nums) {
        std::unordered_set<int> s;
        for (auto& n: nums)
            s.insert(n);
        int ret = 1;
        while (s.find(ret) != s.end())
            ret++;
        
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Why is it faster to add vector elements to an `std::unordered_set` and then loop using `s.find` than to simply loop through the array with `std::find()` function?

Comment: `std::find` simply for-loops over all elements until finding the one. While `std::unordered_map` has efficient lookup table.

Comment: Also it is pretty simple to make a histogram based solution that will run faster than `unordered_set` based for this particular problem.

Comment: There is a trade-of with the extra `if n > 0`. extra conditions in all case to avoid to increase size of the `unordered_map` (and also less chance of collisions, to speed the `find`). In case where most numbers are positive, that check is unneeded and slow down the regular case.